# String replace "<br>↵" with commas in javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, replace

I get the following symbol when I print my array to console: "`<br>↵`"

How do I replace all instances of "`<br>↵`" with commas in a JS array?

e.g.

```
["767 5th Ave<br>↵New York, NY 10153, USA", "677 5th Ave<br>↵New York, NY 10022, USA"]
```

to

```
["767 5th Ave, New York, NY 10153, USA", "677 5th Ave, New York, NY 10022, USA"]
```

The value is taken from:

```
<address class="main">
  <p>767 5th Ave<br>
  New York, NY 10153, USA</p>
</address>
```

with the following code:

```
$("address.main p:not(:empty)").each(function() {
  addresses_google[0].push( $(this).html() );
});
```

Comment: So loop over it and do a string replace on each index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var addresses = ["767 5th Ave<br>↵New York, NY 10153, USA", "677 5th Ave<br>↵New York, NY 10022, USA"];

var formattedAddresses = addresses.map(function(str) {
  return str.replace(/<br>\u21b5/g, ", ");
});

console.log(formattedAddresses);
```

**Update:**

It appears that there's html being pushed into this array with line breaks (interpreted as ↵ symbols, used to visualize a newline) vs. plain string literals.

```
$("address.main p:not(:empty)").each(function() { 
  addresses_google[0].push( $(this).html() );
});
```

Now that we know this is the result of a loop, we could do this all within that loop's code block without the need of even creating a new array:

```
$("address.main p:not(:empty)").each(function() {
  var breaks = /<br>(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm;
  var formattedHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(breaks, ', ');

  addresses_google[0].push(formattedHTML);
});
```

Comment: I get the exact same output.

Comment: Still the same!

Comment: What do you see when you run my snippet?

Comment: The exact same array is returned

Comment: Are you sure? Try refreshing your page. I'm getting the desired result from what you described your post: `["767 5th Ave, New York, NY 10153, USA", "677 5th Ave, New York, NY 10022, USA"]`

Comment: Yes I'm positive. However, the array isn't initialised exactly the same way as in my example (with a "var = ..."), it takes its values from html. When I console.log, it prints as I've outlined in my question.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Are you basing this on **my** output or something completely different on your end? In other words are you trying to implement my answer in some code outside of your original question? Is that where it's not working?

Comment: No, it's the same code, except that the array is not initialised directly but takes its values from html. (the "<br>↵" are not inputted directly in the code). I updated the question for clarity.

Comment: Let's see if we can target that return character via unicode. Try now. Just updated my answer again.

Comment: Thanks for your time! Unfortunately: same result. I'll include the html snippet where the values are taken from in my question. Maybe it's just a javascript line break?

Comment: No problem. Yeah go ahead and do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129848/discussion-between-carl-edwards-and-pim).

Comment: May need to solve for what specific character your looking to change out, but sounds like @CarlEdwards has a good solution.